# UITextField not working through JavaScriptCore iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitextfield, javascriptcore

I recently started exploring JavaSciptCore in iOS 7.

Till now I have been able to use UILabel, UIButton and a few more of the UI elements using JSCore.

But now I am stuck while using the UITextField. For some reason, it does not appear on the screen but all the code is getting executed.

So my .h file has the following in a protocol which is implemented in the interface.

```
- (void)set:(JSValue *)config; 
+ (id)create;
```

In my .m file I have the above functions defined.

```
+ (RZTextField *)create
{
    RZTextField *textField = [[RZTextField alloc] init];
    return textField;
}

-(void)set:(JSValue *)config
{
    if (![config[@"text"] isUndefined]) {
        self.text = [config[@"text"] toString];
    }

    if (![config[@"textColor"] isUndefined]) {
        self.textColor = [Utils makeColor:[config[@"textColor"] toArray]];
    }

    if (![config[@"frame"] isUndefined]) {
        self.frame = [Utils makeFrame:[config[@"frame"] toArray]];
        self.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
        self.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    }

    if (![config[@"background"] isUndefined]) {
        self.background = [Utils makeColor:[config[@"background"] toArray]];
    }
}
```

And finally this is the JS code that gets executed:

```
//root view controller is created
App.rootVC = UI.ViewController.create();
App.rootVC.makeRootViewController();
App.rootVC.set({ background: [231, 76, 60, 1] });

App.textF = UI.TextField.create();
App.textF.set({
  frame:[20, 500, 300, 120],
  text: "some text",
  textColor:[255, 255, 255, 1],
  background:[255, 255, 255, 1]
});
App.rootVC.append(App.textF);
```

I did some debugging on my own so following are the points:
- I have set breakpoints and checked. It goes to all the function calls. So everything is getting executed.
- The root view controller works fine and I have been able to add other UI elements just fine.
- The UITextField gets appended successfully. I know this because when I checked the parent of the text field, it returns the root view controller's address.
- For some reason when I did `initWithFrame:` from the `create` function, then it showed a part of the text field as if the root view controller was partly of the visible screen! So whatever `frame` I set, couldn't see more than half of the textfield!

Any ideas on what's going on?

Comment: Make sure that you do any changes to the text field are on the main thread. I am not posting this as an answer because I am not sure on which thread JSC calls methods.

Comment: JS context is running on main thread.

Comment: It is a bit hard to offer advice without understanding the rest of your code.  For example, are you creating any other controls after the UITextField ?  What happens in the code not shown for makeRootViewController() ?

Comment: You could try adding borders around all controls created to see if anything is obscuring the UITextField.  You could also try setting a breakpoint after the view has been drawn and inspecting the UITextField frame and layer once it is attached to the parent and has been rendered.

Comment: @Mike Well I have done all that. No noting is obscuring it since I have tested with only the UITextField on the view. I did put breakpoints on every line but everything seems fine - proper frame, parent, etc. makeRootViewController() simple makes the rootVC (a view controller) as the root view controller.

Answer (score 0):

I have some experience with `CocoaScript`, the new name for `JSTalk` which is a wrapper around `JavaScriptCore` for OS X. It doesn't run on iOS but as far as I know could be ported, so perhaps you want to try porting it.

- http://jstalk.org
- https://github.com/ccgus/CocoaScript

I'm not sure what CocoaScript does differently, or perhaps you are doing differently, but I have no trouble at all working with text fields in this bit of javascript: https://github.com/abhibeckert/Dux/blob/master/Default-Bundles/Lorem%20Ipsum.coscript